# Recent suggested tag wiki edits

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wikis

Today [Apr 21 '16] and yesterday there were a considerable number of suggested edits
to previously empty tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts (browse [here](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/history);
viewing the full list requires >=10K points, I think), all by the same user. 
These edits mostly didn't really follow the [guidelines on writing good tag
wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), in particular they often didn't make clear which questions should
have the particular tag. On the other hand, having a tag wiki may be 
considered better than having no tag wiki, at least unless the contents
are too unreasonable.
It happens that these tag wiki edits were accepted by some users (like
myself, at least in most cases -- though I don't know whether this was
the 'right' choice), and rejected by others. -- Any opinions?

Comment: It is true that see the suggested edits in [the list you linked](http://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/history) requires some reputation. But I guess that if you link to specific examples of reviews - using links like [this](http://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/63340) or [this](http://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/63350) or [this](http://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/63491), then they will be visible to everybody. (In fact, I tried to view them while not logged in and I saw the review.)

Comment: Another link where these suggested edits could be visible to all users could be link to all [suggested edits of that particular user](http://mathoverflow.net/users/21574/hassan-jolany?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). (This was not intended as pointing to a single user, my intention was to show some examples of suggested edits you mention. But if this is for some reason inappropriate, I - or the moderators - can delete my comments.)

Comment: The recent edits simply copy-paste material from Wikipedia, without attribution.  When done on such a large scale it could be considered a violation of Wikipedia's CC BY-SA license.

Comment: well, some of it is already being improved...

Comment: In light of Dmitri Pavlov's observation, could it be that the user misunderstands the meaning of the word "wiki" in "tag wiki"?

Comment: These posts on Meta Stack Exchange are related to this problem: [Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000) and [Can we do anything against tag wikis copy-pasted from Wikipedia?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102314)

Answer (score 15):

The problem seems to be more serious: the tag wiki edits by this
user seem to copy-paste material from sites like MathWorld,
which requires a license for commercial use
(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/about/faq.html#copyright),
for example, https://mathoverflow.net/tags/axiom-of-choice/info
is copy-pasted from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AxiomofChoice.html.

Some other tag wiki edits by this user copy-paste material from Wikipedia,
which allows commercial use, but requires attribution.
However, no attribution is given.
For example,
https://mathoverflow.net/tags/calculus-of-variations/info
is copy-pasted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations.

Comment: While I agree that this is problematic, I am not sure if this qualifies as commercial use.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: MathOverflow carries advertisements for other StackExchange sites, which are commercial.

Comment: Ahh, good point.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the question, the problematic tag-wikis came mostly from a single user. Since this user has deleted his account in the meantime, they can be no longer found through his profile page. (In case somebody wants to help and improve the tag-wikis which are still missing source/attribution.)

To help with this problem, here are a few [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) queries which might help to find them:

- [Tag-info edits by a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/885912/tag-info-edits-by-a-deleted-user?UserId=21574)
- [Tag wikis created by a deleted user](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/886143/tag-wikis-created-by-a-deleted-user?UserId=21574)
- [Get posts list of a deleted user](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=21574)

Comment: Thanks to rene for his [improvements of the first query](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223/2018/8/12).