# Create usage guidance for 2-categories tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wikis

> The 2-categories tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create
>   it?

This is what the 2-categories tag page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/2-categories says.

Can some one create usage guidance for this?

Comment: I guess the [tag-info for this tag on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/2-categories/info) could be used as a start.

Comment: Actually this is a quotation of Wikipedia (with reference to WIkipedia), so we can just copy it. Actually this tag doesn't seem to be an issue, since it has a precise focussed meaning. In general, a tag-info is particularly important if the scope of the tag is not obvious (e.g., is more than just what is written, or is less, in particular when there are several meanings). In practice, the more a tag is misused, the more a tag-info is needed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: What's the point of copying descriptions from Wikipedia?  How does it help one to decide whether to use the tag or not?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Indeed, for the guidance about the usage of the tag the info from Wikipedia does not help. I assume that the OP of this questions suggested to create the tag-info mainly as a place where some basic info is collected (and/or links to more/info). For such purpose, links to Wikipedia, nLab, etc., might be useful.

Comment: In connection with MO it is worth stressing that some attribution to source of the text should be included, since in the past some tag-wikis were created without that. Se also: [Recent suggested tag wiki edits](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2849) and [Should tag-wiki include a source where it is taken from?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3547)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I do not think that it is appropriate to use the tag info as a “place where some basic info is collected (and/or links to more/info)”.  This directly contradicts the guidelines posted at https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/, which explicitly state “Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized”.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov That's a very reasonable point. OTOH when we look at how tag-infos are actually used on MO, many of them copy-paste material from elsewhere. As you pointed out here: [Recent suggested tag wiki edits](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2849#2854).